# Weird response from API at Litecoin exchange

Tags: api, webrequest

I'm trying to send a POST request to the Livecoin API. I have ensured that every parameter and the encoding is correct, but I keep getting a weird response:

```html
{"success":false,"exception": "Unknown currency pair [currencyPair={1}]|null"}
```

This is what I'm trying to post:

```html
 string response = PrivatePostQuery("exchange/buymarket", "currencyPair=BTC/USD&price=12&amount=12");
```

And this is the method:

```
public string PrivatePostQuery(string requestUrl, string parameters = "")
    {
        parameters = http_build_query(parameters);
        string Sign = HashHMAC(this.Exchange.ExchangeConnection.ApiSecretKey, parameters).ToUpper();
        string uri = this.Exchange.ExchangeConnection.ApiUrl + requestUrl + "?" + parameters;
        byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(parameters);
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
        request.Headers["Api-Key"] = this.Exchange.ExchangeConnection.ApiKey;
        request.Headers["Sign"] = Sign;
        Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        dataStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        try
        {
            WebResponse WebResponse = request.GetResponse();
            dataStream = WebResponse.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader StreamReader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
            return StreamReader.ReadToEnd();
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            return new StreamReader(ex.Response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();

        }


    }
```

I have succeeded getting tickers and my balance from the API, so the problem is not because of the signature or headers.

I have tried changing the request to upper / lower case, and adding the parameters as request headers, with and without them in URL.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Ok so there was no problem at all, LiveCoin exchange doesn't work with BTC-USDT pair, only with BTC-USD. So the response was correct, even tough it was a bit messy.